# Is there an object deletion method?

Tags: c#, class, methods, console

I'm working on a simple console checkers game to test my skills on object-oriented programming in C#. I'm working on the logic portion of when a player takes another player's chip. I currently have it setting the row and column variables (being used to track where it is on the board) back to 0 to symbolize it not being there. However, is there a method that just deletes the object as a whole for the rest of the duration of that run?

Comment: C# has garbage collection, so you don't need to delete the object.  You do need to remove the reference to the object from whatever container/collection you are using.  Do you have a `List` or array or what?

Comment: It's not clear what specifically you mean by "deleting an object" in this case, but if you have an object in memory and there are no more references to that object in scope then the underlying garbage collector generally takes care of freeing up the memory for you.  It's rare to need to dig into the inner workings of that.  Do you have a specific example of something which isn't working as expected or a specific operation in code you're struggling to implement?

Comment: Are you thinking of the `delete` operator in C++? There is nothing equivalent in C#.  The closest is to set the object ref to `null` so it can be garbage-collected. How are you representing the checkers board?

Comment: Setting the obj to `null` and letting it fall out of scope is ideal. Many languages would rather not have programmers having to manually free memory, as its so easy to do something wrong. You do not need to force garbage collection, as it already is running continuously, and manually calling `GC.Collect()` is going to collect all objects possible which may lead to unexpected behavior

Comment: If a variable is going to go out of scope, there's no need to set it to `null` first (in fact, in rare situations, it's possible that putting `someVariable=null;` at the bottom of a method may delay the referred to object from being collected earlier).  As long as an object (of reference type) no longer has any active references, it will _become eligible for garbage collection_. You don't need to worry about deleting objects. You do need to read up on how non-memory resources need to be cleaned up. Read up on the _Dispose Pattern_ and the `using` keyword

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, there is no direct way to delete an object in C# as the language uses garbage collection to manage the memory allocation and deallocation of objects. Garbage collection is a process that automatically removes objects that are no longer referenced by any variable or field. You can’t force the garbage collector to run at a specific time, but you can request it by calling the `GC.Collect()` method. However, this is not recommended as it can degrade the performance of your application.

Instead of trying to delete the object, you can simply set the variable that references it to null. This will remove the reference and make the object eligible for garbage collection. For example, if you have a variable called chip that holds a reference to an object of type Chip, you can do something like this:

```
chip = null; // remove the reference to the chip object
```

This will not delete the object immediately, but it will mark it as unreachable and allow the garbage collector to reclaim its memory when it runs.